# Android. Google Play приложение было приостановлено (suspended). Возможен ли бан аккаунта?

Tags: java, android, google-play

Привет. Залил приложение - из-за не корректного заголовка оно было заблокировано c причиной:

> REASON FOR REJECTION: Violation of the spam provision of the Content Policy. Please refer to the keyword spam policy help article for more information.

Do not use others' branding or product names at the start of your app title without permission. This implies association and is misleading for users. Instead, use "for [ product or brandinsert name ]."
Incorrect: "Android MediaPlayer"
Correct: "MediaPlayer for Android"

Поправил заголовок - залил снова и его заблокировали через несколько месяцев с причиной:

> REASON FOR SUSPENSION:Violation of the impersonation or deceptive
>   behavior provisions of the Content Policy. Please refer to the
>   impersonation policy help article for more information.

Вопрос:

1. Сколько раз еще можно перезалить до бана аккаунта? Банят ли за такое вообще?
2. Как корректно выбирать название приложение? Тематика приложения: DLNA плеер для VK.com. Последний вариант был Air Music for VK в соответствии с рекомендациями, но помогло не на долго.

Comment: Air Music for One Russian Social Network. VK - Нельзя :) хотя потом и без VK вас забанят, потому что там в любом случае нарушение лицензии на музыку.

Comment: @Evgeny Karavashkin Почему других не банят, в том числе оф. приложение?

Comment: Да всех банят, то что вы на 4pda выкладывали ссылки на других не забаненых - там все приложения новые, пару месяцев в маркете. Забанят со временем. У вас видимо Акк уже под наздором, и вы при заливке быстро на модерацию попадаете :)

Comment: @Evgeny Karavashkin, ага, спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Информация о блокировкам несколько неоднозначная, но судя по отзывам разработчиков баннят аккаунт после 3 блокировок приложения.

Comment: Гы, у меня уже 2 бана. Пора менять аккаунт, иначе останусь вообще без почты

Answer (score 1):

Покажу список своих приложений =) 
http://joxi.ru/p27LjkOtLLdNA7
Последнее в списке помечено как "Удалено". Сначала Google разрешил его, и опубликовал без всяких нарушений. Спустя три дня его зареджектили, после этого я раз 5-6 отправлял на повторную проверку, изменив все так, как они хотели. Но как видите толку ноль, но и не забанили =)